# Restrict Duplicate Annotation on MapView

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit, mkannotation

How do i restrict duplicate annotation on unique location of latitude and longitude.

When i am adding annotation on map, i can add annotation on one point having same lat and long, for example i add a pin on the map at lat = 37.785834 and long = -122.406417 and name it as Bob's house then next time when i again add a annotation pin at that place and it takes same lat and long and i can save it as Steve House, but it should not happen i want it to show a type of alert that this location has already occupied, choose a different location, so that no lat long should have duplicate entries.
This has nothing to do with zoom or anything.

now i want a code to query and check in database whether the user is tapping the annotation at the same latitude and longitude ie, i never want to create a duplicate entry for same lat/long value by checking in the database.....

Example code:

```
#pragma mark - 
- (void) addSite2 { 
    AddSiteInfoViewController *vc = [[[AddSiteInfoViewController alloc] initWithCoordinate:pinAnnotation.coordinate] autorelease]; 
    [self.delegate pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: hey how can you able to drop more then one pin on same lat, long.

Comment: if you do not change the pin position and keep on adding annotations on the same location it keeps on adding names at same lat/long .

Comment: can you please provide me sample for this or more explanation..

Comment: #pragma mark - 

- (void) addSite2
{
    AddSiteInfoViewController *vc = [[[AddSiteInfoViewController alloc] initWithCoordinate:pinAnnotation.coordinate] autorelease];
    [self.delegate pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}

Comment: You can maintain an array of all the points added on the map and then next time while adding a new pin you can compare with that array and plot only if there is no pin at that point.

Comment: It'll be much easier to read if you edit the original question and put the code in there than here in the comments.

Comment: how are you saving your lat long..

Comment: i am  taking lat/long  as user's current annotation mark.in database as float value.

Comment: follow my answer in this link and then make condition you will get solution.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14001146/extracting-unique-objects-from-a-data-array/14002160#14002160

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the annotation is already shown in the map, you can use the following code (without having to check the database):

```
#pragma mark - 
- (void) addSite2 { 
    NSUInteger index = [self.mapView.annotations indexOfObjectPassingTest:
                        ^BOOL(MKAnnotation *anot1, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop){
                            return (CLCOORDINATES_EQUAL( anot1.coordinate, pinAnnotation.coordinate));
                    }];
    if (index == NSNotFound)
    {
        AddSiteInfoViewController *vc = [[[AddSiteInfoViewController alloc] initWithCoordinate:pinAnnotation.coordinate] autorelease]; 
        [self.delegate pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
    }
}
```

*(Mostly written on top of my head, so a typo or minor error could exist.)*

If, in fact, the annotation is not shown... use the solution given in the comments by Rajneesh071: [Extracting Unique Objects from a Data Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14001146/extracting-unique-objects-from-a-data-array/14002160#14002160)