# Extracting Unique Objects from a Data Array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I want to add names in a data array only if the name does not previously exist in the data array. When I attempt to print these names, I do get repetitions. Is there a way to solve this?

```
-(NSMutableArray *)autoComplete
{
    NSMutableArray *dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@45.25,-95.25&limit=100&client_id=Von0J4Bu6INiez5bGby2R&client_secret=50sUjSbg7dba8cQgtpdfr5Ns7wyYTqtmKpUU3khQ",kWSURL];
    NSDictionary * returnDict = (NSDictionary *) [self callWebService:url];
    if([returnDict objectForKey:@"success"])
    {
       NSArray *responceArray = [returnDict objectForKey:@"response"];
        for (NSDictionary *dict in responceArray) {

             placeDC *place = [[placeDC alloc]init];
            NSDictionary *placeDict = (NSDictionary *)[dict objectForKey:@"place" ];
            NSDictionary *loctionDict =(NSDictionary *)[dict objectForKey:@"loc"];
            NSString * name =[placeDict objectForKey:@"name"];
            NSString * stateFull =[placeDict objectForKey:@"stateFull"];
            NSString * countryFull =[placeDict objectForKey:@"countryFull"];

            NSString *latitude =[loctionDict objectForKey:@"lat"];
            NSString *longitude = [loctionDict objectForKey:@"long"];
            place.placeNmae=name;
            place.countryFullName=countryFull;
            place.stateFullName=stateFull;
            NSLog(@"%@ ",stateFull);

            place.latitude=[latitude doubleValue];
            place.longitude=[longitude doubleValue];


             [dataArray addObject:place];

        }


    }

    return dataArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Check that is there any response from the Server side or not, to check response use NSLog() or Break Points.

if response is ok then put a the following check your code

```
if (![dataArray containsObject:@"Some Name"])
{

    // add Object

}
```

Comment: check the link and reply me http://api.aerisapi.com/places/closest?p=45.25,-95.25&limit=100&client_id=Von0J4Bu6INiez5bGby2R&client_secret=50sUjSbg7dba8cQgtpdfr5Ns7wyYTqtmKpUU3khQ

Answer (score 1):

You could add the name `NSString` to an `NSSet` and check in every cycle whether it contains it or not.

Inside your `if` you could write something like:

```
NSArray *responceArray = [returnDict objectForKey:@"response"];
NSSet *names = [[NSSet alloc] init];
for (NSDictionary *dict in responceArray) {
     NSDictionary *placeDict = (NSDictionary *)[dict objectForKey:@"place" ];
     NSString * name =[placeDict objectForKey:@"name"];
     if (![names containsObject:name]) {
          [names addObject:name];
          placeDC *place = [[placeDC alloc]init];
          NSDictionary *loctionDict =(NSDictionary *)[dict objectForKey:@"loc"];
          NSString * stateFull =[placeDict objectForKey:@"stateFull"];
          NSString * countryFull =[placeDict objectForKey:@"countryFull"];

          NSString *latitude =[loctionDict objectForKey:@"lat"];
          NSString *longitude = [loctionDict objectForKey:@"long"];
          place.placeNmae=name;
          place.countryFullName=countryFull;
          place.stateFullName=stateFull;
          NSLog(@"%@ ",stateFull);

          place.latitude=[latitude doubleValue];
          place.longitude=[longitude doubleValue];
          [dataArray addObject:place];
     }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Do one thing, add your `dict` in another array and search in this array that data already exist or not,

```
[tempAry addObject: dict];
```

and before insertion

```
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == %@", name];
    NSArray *filteredArray = [tempAry filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    if ([filteredArray count] == 0)
    {
        [dataArray addObject:place];
    }
    else{
        //Already exist
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a separate dictionary, as an ivar or property of you class, for storing our required value, say it as :

```
NSMutableDictionary *uniqueValueDict=[NSMutableDictionary new];
```

And keep storing your required value and key as:

```
[uniqueValueDict setObject:stateFull forKey:uniqueValueDict];
```

Your work will be done.

Comment: he @Anoop Vaidya i want to remove the repetition fron the sate name plz check the link

Comment: http://api.aerisapi.com/places/closest?p=45.25,-95.25&limit=100&client_id=Von0J4Bu6INiez5bGby2R&client_secret=50sUjSbg7dba8cQgtpdfr5Ns7wyYTqtmKpUU3khQ

Comment: You have a responceArray which contains a dict that has placeDict, and in this plceDict you want to remove repitition of states?

Comment: So whats the big deal... I have already given a solution... implement it and finally replace placeDict with uniqueVauleDict. Thats it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest solution that i have applied and this should get you going in picking up unique elements out of array.

```
 NSArray * claimedOfferArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"A",@"C",@"B" nil];
  NSArray * distinctArray = [[NSArray alloc]init]; 
  distinctArray =[[NSSet setWithArray:claimedOfferArray] allObjects];
```

This code will also work with `NSMutableArray`
Let me know if it works for you..:).

Comment: Well this code helps you in extracting the unique elements..in this case..if you put an NSLog for distinct array you should get only A,B,C as its elements in your log..so what exactly isn't working for you?